# Authentication token expiring within 10 seconds instead of 10 minutes

Tags: box-api

We currently have an implementation that uses boxes API.  Our authentication process follows the process outlined here:

http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating

Sometime in the recent past this has stopped working.  When we go to the oauth URL (for example, https://www.box.net/api/1.0/auth/rev37d850p6pixlemm5ok8doxj2g77kg), it will initially show the login credentials page, but faster than a user could reasonably enter their credentials the page starts returning "expired ticket".  If I immediately go to the token's page after creating it I can reload the page a few times before it goes into the "expired ticket" state.  This is clearly not consistent with the expected 10 minute expiry time stated in the documentation.

We've had this authentication working correctly up to now, so it seems like something has changed.

Comment: We are having the same issue with our Android app.  Looks like there's an issue on Box's side that theyre working on.

Comment: Same problem. Getting "expired ticket" in login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are investigating.    More news once we have some additional information.

New info>> We've identified the bug, and will be pushing a fix this afternoon.

The fix has been rolled out.   Please let us know if you are still experiencing any problems with SSO.

Comment: this has been down for over 30 hours now.  What's taking so long? I'm sure this is affecting a lot of developers using your API but it doesnt seem to be a priority for you guys...

Comment: Basically it depends on how you are watching the user's interaction with our site.  If you are hitting get_auth_token very aggressively, before the user has even been sent to the SSO site, then we were treating that as an attack, and shutting it down.  Apps that were giving the user a little time to logon were not seeing this problem.  Fix should be out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Our Android app has the same problem. As far as I investigated it, using get_auth_token API causes the ticket to expire. So you have to make sure the user has successfully logged in BEFORE attempting to get the authentication token (which is not the case with Box SDK for Android). But I don't see a viable way to check whether the user has logged in.